# iPhone: Adjust the box to the contents inside

Tags: iphone, layout

I have a list of boxes to show.
Each box has a padding and 3 text elements. These elements can have different size.
I'm trying to make them always having the same padding, and space around them, but I can not adjust them since I don't know how to calculate the resulting size of each one.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|    (10px padding all over the box)                      |
|                                                         |
|      +-------------------------------------------+      |
|      |  a box with a text                        |      | 
|      +-------------------------------------------+      |
|              (between boxes the same space)             |
|      +-------------------------------------------+      |
|      |  a box with a text                        |      | 
|      +-------------------------------------------+      |
|                                                         |
|      +-------------------------------------------+      |
|      |  a box with a text                        |      | 
|      +-------------------------------------------+      |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I mean, in HTML it would be a simple table with cell-padding 10px.

Is this possible in iPhone ? Some developers told me it can not be done AS THIS, and this is because the solution is to define that a text occupies (for example) JUST ONE LINE, and the text has to be cut ending with "..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you know following things

- max width
- string to be tested
- font size

you can calculate the height required for the label even for multiple line breaks using following method

```
+  (CGSize) calculateLabelHeightWith:(CGFloat)width text:(NSString*)textString
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

**iOS 7 update**

```
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:<text Feild Size>
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont stuff here]}
                                 context:nil];

CGSize size = textRect.size;
```

So you will get height of each label and then use it to get total height+10px padding